# Postgres join categories

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I need to join subcategories to general categories, I have page with list of all categories and subcategories, subcategories have one category array ex. cat = {10,17}, that array contains ids of general categories.
I need to join subcategories names to general categories. 
ex.

```
cat_id = 1, -> general category ID
name = 'Music', -> general category name
subcats = {'Rock', 'Bla', 'Bla'} -> joined subcategories
```

This query list all categories and subcategories

```
SELECT * FROM event.kat k ORDER BY k.kat_id
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a subcategory table?

Comment: I don't have it, i'm not owner of this database, but if I was I would create table with subcategories  :(

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor your schema if possible. At the outset I see at least three tables: categories, subcategories, and category_subcategory, which acts as a join table between the first two tables. In that case it's easy to do "select ... from categories join category_subcategory join subcategories".

If you're absolutely stuck with this setup, you can do something like

```
select ...
from event.kat k
       join <subcategories table> s
         on k.kat_id = any (s.subcats)
```